# document.write('<scr'+'ipt ... not working

Tags: javascript, html

The following script works like a sharm:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">alert("werwer")</sc'+'ript>');
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VHLTx/

But this one does not! why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() {
    $location =  geoplugin_countryName();    

    if($location == "Canada" || $location == "United States") {
      // >>>some code>>>
    } else {
      document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">alert("werwer")</sc'+'ript>');
    } 
});
</script>
```

please help me an example using jsfiddle is very welcomed

thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3kMt/1/ --> it does not show the message

Comment: .getScript() is probably failing altogether. Check your console for errors.

Comment: no its working http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/WktTV/

Comment: It's working in that fiddle because jQuery is selected on the left hand side of the page.  In the not-working example, MooTools is selected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454421/javascript-call-not-calling

Answer (score 5):

The **real** reason it's never going to work is that your `document.write()` call will happen in the asynchronous callback to the `$.getScript()` call.  That'll happen **after** the original document has been closed.

The result will be that the rest of the original page will be completely obliterated.

It's not clear what the point of that use of `document.write()` might be anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`getScript` is a jQuery method, your jsfiddle is configured to load MooTools.

An example using jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VHLTx/1/

Comment: It still won't work; it'll almost certainly end up doing the `document.write()` call after the document is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery to use `getScript()`.  The console errors on the not-working fiddle you provided (http://jsfiddle.net/g3kMt/1) show that `getScript()` is an undefined method.  The settings show that you are loading MooTools, not jQuery.

Here's an updated version that works: http://jsfiddle.net/g3kMt/2/  All I did was change the pull-down menu to specify jQuery rather than MooTools.  In your actual code to run on your site or whatever, you'll need to make sure you are loading jQuery.

And here's a version you can cut and paste into an HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">   
    $.getScript('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', function() {      
        $location =  geoplugin_countryName();            
        if($location == "Canada" || $location == "United States") {
            document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">alert("werwer")</sc'+'ript>');       
        } else {    
            document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">alert("werwer")</sc'+'ript>');         
        }   
    });  
</script>
```

As Pointy explains, the approach your taking here will obliterate any other content on the page. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Well, it will work...but it will just (as you wrote in your answer) obliterate the rest of the page. Which, yeah, is probably not what the OP intends.